# How do I find all non-overlapping combinations?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to find all possible non-overlapping combinations of items which are grouped into buckets.  There may be any number of buckets, and each bucket may contain any number of items.  A valid combination will contain exactly 1 item from each bucket.

```
bucket   item  start end
========================

      |-- I1     1    5
B1----|-- I2     6    9
      |-- I3    15    20


      |-- I4    6     9
B2----|-- I5    10    14
      |-- I6    14    25


      |-- I7    1     14
B3----|-- I8    26    40
      |-- I9    1     20
      |-- In ...

Bn ...
```

For example, we could do items 1,4,8; 1,5,8; 1,6,8; 2,5,8; 2,6,8; 3,4,8; and 3,5,8.

We can observe that item 9 does not appear in a combination because it overlaps with all of the items in bucket 1, leaving no options.

How do I best solve this problem efficiently?  I'm implementing this in browser JavaScript.

Comment: You should probably explain when and how the buckets are filled.

Comment: You should use interval trees to hold each bucket (and partial solution while solving it). Other than that, this looks like a NP complete problem.

Comment: @popnoodles: I start with a simple array of objects.  `[{ bucket: Bn, id: In, start: x, end: y }, ... ]`

Comment: I don't understand the question; what does "non-overlapping" mean in this context? And where do  the 3,4,8 and 2 values in your example come from? I don't see them in the illustration of the buckets.

Comment: @G.Bach: Non-overlapping means that the range of numbers between the start and end values of an item do not coincide with another items'.  For example I1 (1-5) and I4 (6-9) do not overlap, but I1 and I7 (1-14) overlap on 1,2,3,4, and 5.  The numbers in the example refer to item numbers (such as `I1`) in the illustration.

Comment: @ElKamina: I was afraid this problem might be NPC.

Comment: @josh3736 As I demonstrate in my answer, brute force is combinational in the number of buckets. It is fortunately linear in the product of the sizes of each bucket, which means you can add more items without blowing out your computation time, but be careful how many buckets you use. I need to give more thought to if interval overlap could be made nlogn in the number of buckets; it feels like it should just be a sort.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach is to generate the cartesian product of the buckets, and filter out any that are invalid. So, assuming your buckets are simply lists of items, something along the lines of:

```
var cp = _.flatten(_.flatten(_.map(B1, function(item1) {
    return _.map(B2, function(item2) {
        return _.map(B3, function(item3) {
            return [item1, item2, item3];
        });
    });
}), true), true);
```

Will give you the cartesian product of 3 buckets.

```
_.filter(cp, function(tuple) {
    return !overlaps(item1, item2) && !overlaps(item1, item3) && !(overlaps(item2, item3);
});
```

will filter out the ones you don't want (given a suitable definition of overlaps).

```
function overlaps(a, b) {
    return a.lower > b.upper || b.lower > a.upper;
}
```

You can generalise the filter to any number of intervals by converting the cartesian product to a recursive call calculating the flattened expansion of _.first(args) over the cartesian product of _.rest(args).

You can generalise the filter to any number of intervals by generating all possible pairs, and calling `!_.any(pairs, function(pair) { return overlaps.prototype.apply(undefined, pair); });`.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't originally clear in the question -- I don't know ahead of time how many buckets will be computed.  (Number of buckets depends on the dataset and user selections.)

Comment: In that case I will need to know if this is homework before I proceed. I have given you enough to help you solve the problem if this is hw, otherwise I can come back later when I have a bit more time and flesh out the recursive calls required to generalise this to n-buckets.

Comment: Nope, real world problem.  (Perhaps I have a future in writing textbooks?)

Comment: No problem. It is the sort of problem that might be assigned as homework for an algorithms class. I'll try to take another look at it later.